# Qt UTF-8 File to std::string Adds extra characters

Tags: c++, string, qt, utf-8

I have a UTF-8 encoded text file, which has characters such as ²,³,Ç and ó. When I read the file using the below, the file appears to be read appropriately (at least according to what I can see in Visual Studio's editor when viewing the contents of the `contents` variable)

```
QFile file( filePath );
if ( !file.open( QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text ) ) {
    return;
}
QString contents;
QTextStream stream( &file );
contents.append( stream.readAll() );
file.close();
```

However, as soon as the contents get converted to an `std::string` the additional characters are added. For example, the `²` gets converted to `Ã‚Â²`, when it should just be Â². This appears to happen for every non-ANSI character, the extra `Ã‚` is added, which, of course, means that when the a new file is saved, the characters are not correct in the output file.

I have, of course, tried simply doing `toStdString()`, I've also tried `toUtf8` and have even tried using the `QTextCodec` but each fails to give the proper values.

I do not understand why going from UTF-8 file, to QString, then to std::string loses the UTF-8 characters. It should be able to reproduce the exact file that was originally read, or am I completely missing something?

Comment: Is the extra character in the string itself? Have you checked using a debugger? Or do you see it only when printing (in which case it might be the printing that is flawed, either the code or the set locale or the terminal you print to). In short, can you please tell us how you check the contents of the string.

Comment: When using the TextVisualizer of the QString, I see `Â²` (as expected), when viewing the TextVisualizer of the std::string (immediately after calling toStdString) I see `Ã‚Â²`, so it is before the file is written to. I can also view the files (before and after) in Notepad++ in ANSI (which shows the above characters) and in UTF-8 which shows `²` for the original, and `Â²` for the new file. It seems a bit like the UTF-8 version is showing what it should be for ANSI.

Comment: Please don't use ANSI when talking about character encodings, because there is no encoding with that name. This is just a misnomer that Windows uses to mean "the code page according to the current regional settings", which leads to "ANSI" text files being almost always not portable across different-language versions of Windows.

Comment: BTW. Please post actual hex dumps of the data that you're processing, and how they look like after being passed through `QString` and `std::string`. Also, it appears that `QTextStream` is prepared to handle UTF-16 by default unless a BOM appears : have you tried reading the file to a `QByteArray` and using `QString::fromUtf8`? This also has the added advantage of being explicit about what you're doing in terms of character encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel Kamil Kozar mentioned in his answer, the `QTextStream` does not read in the encoding, and, therefore, does not actually read the file correctly. The `QTextStream` must set its Codec prior to reading the file in order to properly parse the characters. Added a comment to the code below to show the extra file needed.

```
QFile file( filePath );
if ( !file.open( QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text ) ) {
    return;
}
QString contents;
QTextStream stream( &file );
stream.setCodec( QTextCodec::codecForName( "UTF-8" ) ); // This is required.
contents.append( stream.readAll() );
file.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is actually the expected behaviour.

The string `Â²` consists of the bytes `C3 82 C2 B2` when encoded as UTF-8. Assuming that `QTextStream` actually recognises UTF-8 correctly (which isn't all that obvious, [judging from the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#setAutoDetectUnicode), which only mentions character encoding detection when there's a BOM present, and you haven't said anything about the input file having a BOM), we can assume that the `QString` which is returned by `QTextStream::readAll` actually contains the string `Â²`.

`QString::toStdString()` [returns a UTF-8 encoded variant](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toStdString) of the string that the given `QString` represents, so the return value should contain the same bytes as the input file - namely `C3 82 C2 B2`.

Now, about what you're seeing in the debugger :

1. You've stated in one of the comments that "QString only has `0xC2 0xB2` in the string (which is correct).". This is only partially true : QString uses UTF-16LE internally, which means that its internal character array contains two 16-bit values : `0x00C2 0x00B2`. These, in fact, map to the characters `Â` and `²` when each is encoded as UTF-16, which proves that the `QString` is constructed correctly based on the input from the file. However, your debugger seems to be smart enough to know that the bytes which make up a `QString` are encoded in UTF-16 and thus renders the characters correctly.
2. You've also stated that the debugger shows the content of the `std::string` returned from `QString::toStdString` as `Ã‚Â²`. Assuming that your debugger uses the dreaded "ANSI code page" for resolving bytes to characters when no encoding is stated explicitly, and you're using a English-language Windows which uses Windows-1252 as its default legacy code page, everything fits into place : the `std::string` actually contains the bytes `C3 82 C2 B2`, which map to the characters `Ã‚Â²` in [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set).

Shameless self plug : I [delivered a talk about character encodings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5Q3yMIK5XQ) at a conference last year. Perhaps watching it will help you understand some of these problems better.

One last thing : **ANSI is not an encoding**. It can mean a number of different encodings based on Windows' regional settings.

Comment: Hi Daniel, after looking at the memory dump of the QString, it does seem that `QTextStream` is reading the UTF-8 character as two ASCII characters. The file does not have a BOM, as it is not recommended for UTF-8 files. The QTextStream needs to have its encoding set prior to reading the file.

Comment: (sigh) They can't be *ASCII characters* ... never mind.

Comment: Daniel, could you explain what you mean by that? Perhaps I just used the wrong word? QTextStream interpreted the `²` as two separate characters (not ASCII)?